# Excel-DNA makes Excel startup take a long time

Tags: c#, excel-addins, excel-dna

I have a few excel addins that I built with excel-DNA and they work well but the users are complaining that it takes a long time to open Excel every time.

If they uninstall the addins, excel opens much faster. so really is my addins that causes the issue.

I dont have anything on the AutoOpen of any addin BTW... It is just the time it takes to load the XLL

How can I speed up this process?

Comment: Follow-up questions on the Excel-DNA forum here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/XB0NOMXobNQ

Comment: Can you check if your anti virus is scanning the assembly or anything that it is dependent on? I had issues in the past with a different add-in framework which caused a similar issue.

Comment: I still don't have a solution for this... :(

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried and what else you've noticed that might be causing the issue. As an example, recreate the problem on a machine, then try temporarily turning off the antivirus, and see if it corrects the problem. If so, we can understand whats causing the problem and hone in on the issue. If not, we'll be able to focus on what else might be causing the problem.

Comment: How many libraries/resources does your add-in reference?

Comment: @BobbyJ Tried on a clean Windows 7 machine, with a fresh install of Office 2013. Same problem...

Comment: @JamesFaix about 10 assemblies

Comment: Can you replicate the slow loading on your machine, or only on other users machines?  Have you tried disabling one addin at a time, to see if its only one that's causing the issue?  Are your add-ins only referencing Framework libraries and ExcelDNA, or are there other obscure assemblies?  Are you distributing those dependencies with your addin assembly, or are you relying on the GAC?  Is Excel loading addins from the C:\ drive, or a network drive?